# How to export only data from a database in SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to export my data base in parts, like the tables, the data, etc.
So I would like to know how i can export only the data from a date base in SQL developer preferebly in the application tools.

Comment: If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Developer you can do it from **Tools --> Database export**

You need to select the connection and then select the following options according to the requirement:

- Only DDL, select "Export DDL" and unselect "Export Data".
- Only data, select "Export Data" and unselect "Export DDL".

Then in Next screens, You will be able to find some configurations for export and then finally you can do export in .sql file.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Suggested option to export DDL and Data is `IMPDP`.

Cheers!!